# Handling Exception in java Piped Streams

Tags: java, xml, exception, stream-processing, java-threads

I have a xmlStream which I am converting to jsonStream using `org.apache.wink.json4j.utils.XML`. Here is the code

```
public void process(InputStream xmlStream) {
    final BufferedInputStream bufferedXmlStream = new BufferedInputStream(xmlStream);

    PipedInputStream pipedJsonInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    final PipedOutputStream jsonStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedJsonInputStream);
    Thread xmlToJsonThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // put your code that writes data to the outputstream here.
            try {
                XML.toJson(bufferedXmlStream, jsonStream, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    xmlToJsonThread.setDaemon(true);
    xmlToJsonThread.start();

    //process data from piped stream
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            pipedJsonInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    try {
        // use reader to further process json in main thread...
        parseJsonStream(reader);
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        jsonStream.close();
    }
}
```

When XML.toJson throws exception I see that main thread does not exit.
How do I handle this ?
Do you guys think this is a good way of converting XML stream to Json stream for further processing ? I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You certainly need to make sure that `jsonStream` gets closed, preferably in a `finally` block.

Comment: EJP, thanks for looking at this. The exception is "SAXParseException: The entity "trade" was referenced, but not declared". I can potentially modify the xml to declare the entities and solve the issue. But this revealed a bug in my code - when exception is thrown I am seeing that the main program is not exiting. I have already set the thread to be daemon, anything else I should be doing ?

Comment: Yes, I have closed the resources. I updated the code to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the exception on the child thread needs to get reported back to the main thread. This can be tricky to do unless you put both the reader and writer in separate threads.

The way I do this is to wrap both pieces in an `ExecutionCompletionService` - like this:

```
public void process(InputStream xmlStream) {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    ExecutorCompletionService<Void> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(threadPool);

    final BufferedInputStream bufferedXmlStream = new BufferedInputStream(xmlStream);

    PipedInputStream pipedJsonInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
    final PipedOutputStream jsonStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedJsonInputStream);

    ecs.submit( new Callable<Void>() {
       @Override
       public Void call() {
          // put your code that writes data to the outputstream here.
          try {
              XML.toJson(bufferedXmlStream, jsonStream, true);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              throw e;
          }
          return null;
        }
    });

    ecs.submit( new Callable<Void>() {
       @Override
       public Void call() {
          try {
              // use reader to further process json in main thread...
              parseJsonStream(reader);
          } finally {
              reader.close();
              jsonStream.close();
          }
          return null;
      }
    });

    // Wait for all tasks to be done.
    // Kill the other thread if one hits an exception.
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            ecs.take().get();
        }
    } finally {
        threadPool.shutdownNow();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Michael, this worked like charm, appreciate your help!